# Serve single instance of a domain to subscriber audience with MODX

Tags: modx-revolution

Can MODX serve a single site instance to a subscriber-based audience, whereby common elements are served to all users, while each individual subscriber's content is stored uniquely and presented in the front end only to them?

To clarify this scenario, consider a website that provides financial budgeting tools. In this example, a single instance of the website and its components is served to all users, simplifying maintenance, progressive design enhancements, etc., while each user's data (i.e. their financial details) is accessible only to them via log-in credentials.

The default MODX setup does not to support this example. Static elements can be used, but this alone doesn't cover the above scenario. So my question is whether MODX can support the above scenario, and if so, how it can be accomplished? I'm not looking for specific details -- but broadly, what options exist? If there are options, is it even a good choice for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

MODX does an excellent job with common pages, and the built-in ACL system will allow you to differentiate access for any number of closed participants groups.

As for the user's personal data, there are two possible ways: create some custom code or use an existing one. Each of these paths will almost certainly extend the current user model and use it for your needs.

Here are a couple of useful links regarding your question:

https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extending-modx/custom-users

https://docs.modx.com/3.x/en/extras/login/login.tutorials/using-custom-fields

https://modx.com/extras/package/classextender